# How to restored default keymap without restarting Emacs?

Tags: emacs, keymapping

I've somehow corrupted the key bindings in my current Emacs session.

Specifically, typing `shift-M` produces "m", rather than "M".  This problem affects only the `M` key<sup>1</sup>.

My question is: how can I restore the default key bindings ***without restarting Emacs***?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>I'm confident that the problem is a corrupted Emacs keymap.  Typing the same `shift-M` key combination in other applications, or in other Emacs sessions (but, of course, still using the same keyboard, computer, etc.) produces the correct "M".  Incidentally typing `m` (without `shift-`) in the Emacs session with the corrupted keymap works fine; it produces "m", as expected.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> say?  If it got rebound, that call will tell you what it is bound to.  It should be bound to `self-insert-command`.

Something like `(global-set-key (kbd "M")   'self-insert-command)` should do the trick to set it back.  You can execute that using `ielm` or <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>:</kbd>.  You might need to cut and paste the capital M from another app to type that, though.

Comment: `C-Q S-m` should insert `M` even if `S-m` has been rebound